# Can we use one Windows Phone 7 registration for multiple devices?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a windows registration id and have also paid the $99 fee for the annual developer subscription.Presently i am using HTC HD7 for testing my apps.Is it possible to use same registration id for Samsung Focus or any other Windows Phone 7? Or i will have to pay $99 again for using another device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have 3 registered unlocked devices at one time. It is possible to remove device registrations to free up a lot, but that will re-lock the device that you remove.

Comment: Thanx a lot for ur reply..Sorry for reconfirming but 3 registered devices with the same id is possible ?

Comment: Second Derek. You can have up to 3 registered WP7 devices tied to your developer Marketplace account.

Comment: Yes, 3 registered devices from the same developer account (single Windows Live ID).

Answer (score 0):

If I remember my formation, one license comes with 2 WP7 phones and 3 Xboxes.

Comment: Thanx a lot for ur reply..2 WP7 means two devices are allowed? Can u provide me any link related to it.

Comment: Well I've got some slide when I was at microsoft, and it's written on it : "This cost $99 a year and allow you to publish any number of free applications and up to 5 free applications". The presenter tell us you can unlock 2 WP7 and 3 Xboxes for dev purposes (Or maybe 3WP7 and 2 Xboxes... I'm looking in my notes to be sure). I guess you can find this in the SDK documentation and the developer training kit.